# Android - getting current location through Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an app related to Google map. I have done following steps successfully.

1. Created API key to access Google Map
2. Added Google Play Services Library in my app
3. Added required permissions
4. Added map in my activity with `SupportMapFragment`
5. Added a separate class `MyMap.java` to manipulate the map
6. Passed tow parameters to this class - `Context` of main activity and object of `GoogleMap`
7. Turned Wi-Fi and GPS on and ran the app

After this I am getting map with nice look and controls.

**MyMap.java**

```
public class MyMap implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Context context;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient client = null;

    public MyMap(Context context, GoogleMap map) {
        this.context = context;
        this.map = map;

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", 1).show();

        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(client);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {

            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + ","
                            + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 1)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Problem**

In the above class I want to toast the current location. But it is not toasting anything. At least I need to see a toast saying "connected" on `onConnected`
event. Is there something wrong in my implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you create MyMap? I thess problem is `context` but we cannot see what are you sending to it...

Comment: I am sending 'this' from my main activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seemingly never [connect](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect%28%29) your client so it would be a real suprise if `onConnected` was called :)

You create your client with

```
 client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
```

but for the client to do something you have to add:

```
client.connect();
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot. I have used connect() method with my 'cllient' object. It is working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: You can accept my answer then when you can. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

getLastLocation() is going to give location only once. To get periodic location updates, you need to override onLocationChanged() method. You can get this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for this also.

Answer (score 1):

**Best way** that I found is simple implement you activity like so:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener
```

and override method

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
}
```

And don't forget about `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` and `mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);` in map init method

**That's all!**

Also, you can check is map available like here:

```
public boolean checkMapsAvailable() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, 9001);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Constants.showToast(Constants.ALERT_GOOGLEPLAY_CONNECTION);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.